# Active Directory Integration in Windows Phone App

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, active-directory, activedirectorymembership

I need my Windows Phone App users to be authenticated with Active Directory. How to achieve this?

Comment: what do you mean by Active Directory ??

Comment: Microsoft Windows Active directory  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746492(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Authenticated into what? The phone itself, some applications or all applications? Check out http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj733652.aspx.

Comment: Authenticated to use my App. So the authentication should happen with the User data in Active directory and then if authenticated the user can access various features of my app.